# How to stop bottom sheet scrolling when user stops dragging?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way to stop bottom sheet reveal to stop when user lifts the finger (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP), What i am seeing is bottom sheet always move up to reveal entire content.

I implemented a custom bottom sheet behavior but that doesn't seem to be doing the trick. here is the code for the bottom sheet behavior java code.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;


public class LockableBottomSheetBehavior\<V extends View\> extends BottomSheetBehavior<V> {

    public LockableBottomSheetBehavior() {}

    public LockableBottomSheetBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout parent, V child, MotionEvent event) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(parent, child, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout parent, V child, MotionEvent event) {


        int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);
        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING) {
            Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
            child.getGlobalVisibleRect(scrollBounds); //Should we set height of
            setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(parent, child, event);;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, V child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {

        return super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, directTargetChild, target, nestedScrollAxes);

    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedPreScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, V child, View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed) {
        super.onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dx, dy, consumed);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, V child, View target) {
        super.onStopNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNestedPreFling(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, V child, View target, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        return super.onNestedPreFling(coordinatorLayout, child, target, velocityX, velocityY);
    }
}`
```

Also here is the layout file I am working with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mayojava.sample.bottomsheetdemo.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_image_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/map_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/map"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/show_view_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="Show Bottom Sheet"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/layout_bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="400dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.snijsure.sample.bottomsheetdemo.LockableBottomSheetBehavior"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_text1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="@string/title1"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_curate_images"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/title_text1"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:visibility="visible"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_text2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/recycler_curate_images"
                android:text="@string/title2"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_curate_images_second"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/title_text2"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:visibility="visible"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[This is link to video](https://youtu.be/S2Wwu3TwDag)

Comment: In your onTouch event, you are setting the state to expanded, that could be the possible reason. Try setting the state to Collapsed.

Comment: Hello Nipun, reason I am setting state as EXPANDED is because I want bottom view to "stop"  making the sheet bigger. However that makes me think I should record what the state was when the "drag" event started i.e. record state in ACTION_DOWN and transition to opposite state in ACTION_UP. I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

For its worth, I implemented a solution using `ObservableScrollView`. If anyone is interested [sample is located at](https://github.com/snijsure/BottomSlideLayout). You can also find [Youtube video implementation here](https://youtu.be/T6jAWLSYgQA)

Hope it helps if anyone is looking to implement something like this in future.